# How to filter based on monadic pattern match?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, filtering, option-type

I have the following problem:

Given a type `data T = T (Maybe Int)`, how can I filter  a list getting the non-`Nothing` values?

**Input**

```
a = [T (Just 3), T Nothing, T (Just 4)]
```

**Desired Output**

```
b = [T (Just 3), T (Just 4)]
```

I have tried something like :

```
b = filter (\x-> x@(Just t)) a
```

...thinking that I can filter based on a pattern match but i get the error:

```
Pattern syntax in expression context: x@(Just t)
    Did you mean to enable TypeApplications?
```

[I want to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315431/how-to-filter-based-on-monadic-pattern-match#comment91578571_52315450) later on be able to unpack the inner value (under `Just`) and use it accordingly.

Comment: you could use `filter (\x -> case x of (Just _) -> True ; _ -> False) a ` or even `filter (\case (Just _) -> True ; _ -> False)` (the latter with the LambdaCase extention).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think here we can better use the pattern-matching semantics of list comprehension:

```
result = [ e | e@(T (Just _)) <- a]
```

Here we thus enumerate over the elements `e` in `a`, and if the pattern matching with `T (Just _)` succeeds, we yield it in the result list.

If you however wish to *unpack* the values encapsulated in the `T (Just x)`, we thus can perform pattern matching, and yield the wrapped element:

```
result = [ e | T (Just e) <- a]
```

This will thus not only "filter" the values, but unpack concurrently. So the `T Nothing`s are ignored, and only the wrapped `T (Just e)`s are retained and the corresponding `e`s end up in the list.

Comment: This answers the letter of the question, but I bet `[e | T (Just e) <- a]` answers the spirit of the question better.

Comment: Yes that is precisely what i wanted to later on be able to unpack the inner value and use it accordingly.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: see update.

Comment: Could you please tell me why do i get `Pattern bindings not allowed in instance declaration` for  `instance Show File where ; (Dfile ls)=Data.List.intercalate ',' [show e|T (Just e) <- ls]`.Might deserve a separate question but i am not sure. though.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian You probably mean `... where show (Dfile ls)= ...`

Comment: Yes i am sorry i forgot to add that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a list of the `Int` values in your list of `T`s (so typed `[T] -> [Int]`), then [`mapMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe) from `Data.Maybe` already does almost exactly what you want. All you need on top of that is a unwrapping function of type `T -> Maybe Int`

```
import Data.Maybe ( mapMaybe )

data T = T (Maybe Int)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

unT :: T -> Maybe Int
unT (T x) = x

filterTs = mapMaybe unT
```

Then:

```
λ a = [T (Just 3), T Nothing, T (Just 4)]
a :: [T]

λ filterTs a
[3,4]
it :: [Int]
```

In my opinion having this filter operation be of type `[T] -> [Int]` is more useful than having it return the `T` values containing non-`Nothing` values; the reason is that even if you filter `a` down to `[T (Just 3), T (Just 4)]`, then the code that deals with that later *still* has to pattern match on the `Just` to get at the `Int` values, even though you know there'll never be a `Nothing`<sup>1</sup>, because `T` is still hardcoded to contain `Nothing`.

As a general rule, if you're filtering (or defaulting, or etc) to guarantee the absence of a case, you should consider transforming to a type that doesn't have the case anymore. It usually makes the resulting data easier to deal with (no need for pattern matches or `fmap`s to get inside the redundant layers, for example), as well as helping avoid bugs.

There's also `catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`, that does this "filtering out `Nothing`s without mapping", but since you're mapping to unwrapp the `T` constructor `mapMaybe` is a closer fit.

---

<sup>1</sup> And this "I know there'll never be `Nothing` here, so I don't have to handle it" situation is a very rich source of bugs, liable to break when something changes that hidden invariant in future. So it's not even a great idea to actually write code that takes advantage of that knowledge that `Nothing` "cannot" be there; you should *still* handle both cases!

Comment: Thank you for your observations, they are very valuable for me as a beginner.I wanted to know as a rules of thumb, whenever i have nested `maybe`-s in my types like in the example oyu provided with `T` i should make methods that pattern-match and get the field value ? (in your example `unT`)?

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching only works in the *argument* to the function, not the body. The pattern you need to match on is `T`, with a catamorphism like `maybe` to convert the wrapped value to a boolean.

```
Prelude> a = [T (Just 3), T Nothing, T (Just 4)]
Prelude> filter (\(T x) -> maybe False (const True) x) a
[T (Just 3),T (Just 4)]
```

Note, however, that `maybe False (const True)` is already defined as `Data.Maybe.isJust`.

```
Prelude> import Data.Maybe
Prelude> filter (\(T x) -> isJust x) a
[T (Just 3),T (Just 4)]
```

You can simplify the predicate if you have some function of type `T -> Maybe Int` to compose with `isJust`. For instance:

```
Prelude> data T = T { getT :: Maybe Int } deriving Show
Prelude> a = [T (Just 3), T Nothing, T (Just 4)]
Prelude> filter (isJust . getT) a
[T {getT = Just 3},T {getT = Just 4}]
```